# Syntax Error in ActionScript function

Tags: actionscript, syntax

it seems there is an error in the code below, but where?

```
function cloneLoader(source:Loader):Loader
 {
  var clone:Loader = new Loader();
  clone.loadBytes(source.contentLoaderInfo.bytes);
  return clone;
};
```

Comment: For one, **that is not JavaScript**. It's ActionScript. I'm not retagging the question though as I may very well totally change its meaning...

Comment: The guy is new here. I retagged the question.

Comment: @goreSplatter: I know, I was thinking in the perspective of genuinely confusing JS and AS, or just slipping up in the tags. That's what I'm not too certain of. Thanks for the retag though.

Comment: @Sean: Does the compiler point anywhere in your code where it specifically says there's an error?

Comment: @Sean could u paste the error from the output/console ? Alos check if the source loader is loaded/ready(source.contentLoaderInfo.bytes is not null), also look for security issues/cross domain policy file (if the source loaded content is on the same domain (let's call it A) as the domain where the clone is created, then it should be fine, but if your passing content from domain A to another domain(let's call it B), then domain A should allow domain B to access the content through a crossdomain.xml policy file)

Answer (score 0):

clone.loadBytes is an asynchronous call. So you probably can't use the returned object right away.

Maybe try  `return Loader(ObjectUtil.clone(source));`

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in the code as such, nothing wrong with the syntax, it will work fine if source is a Loader.

What error message do you get?